# Ext.js- Change icon inside toolbar based on a value

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm devoloping a project in which i need to the icon depending on the state of the connection to the server. I'm using Ping|Pong method to check connection status.

```
getClass: function (countPing) {
    if (countPing == 1) {
        return 'high';
    } else if (countPing == 2) {
        return 'medium';
    } else if (countPing == 3) {
        return 'low';
     } else {
         return 'no';
      }
    }
 });
```

My toobar structure https://pastebin.com/dzs86smZ

How do i place this icon ('high', 'medium', 'low', 'no') inside my toolbar?

Comment: Can you give more details of your code and problem, or simply share a fiddle?

Comment: I did not put everything here so the question does not get too extensive

Comment: Cannot answer the question like this, because your code structure is unclear. Please at least add the following: where do you intend to place the code from the question in your code; which icon shall change; are you using Sencha Cmd; which ExtJS version?

Comment: The icon that should change is a wifi icon, I am using the sencha 6.2
The toolbar structure is in the pastebin link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a formula in your view model. Here is a rough sample of how it would work, except obviously you would want to replace the binding of text to the icon or iconCls property on the button:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var tb = new Ext.toolbar.Toolbar({
            renderTo: document.body,
            viewModel: {
                data: {
                    status: 1
                },
                formulas: {
                    connectionStatus: function(get) {
                        var v = get('status');
                        switch (v) {
                            case 1: return 'foo';
                            case 2: return 'bar';
                            case 3: return 'baz';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            items: [{
                bind: {
                    text: '{connectionStatus}'
                }
            }]
        });

        setInterval(function() {
            var n = Ext.Number.randomInt(1, 3);
            tb.getViewModel().set('status', n);
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess 'getClass' method is not in the same class. So you will need to fire Global event and listen for it in 'ES.view.Layout.Toolbar.Toolbar'. You will pass icon size as argument. Then, since you will be in the scope you can get reference on your image and simply change its src property with 'setSrc' method.